# Установка двух условий для цикла While

Tags: python

Возможно ли установить для While два условия. К примеру:

```
While number1 > 0 or number2 >0:
     ...
```

Comment: Да, это возможно.

Comment: Вообще-то это одно, пусть и комплексное, условие. Условие - это выражение, возвращающее результат булева типа, и оно может быть любой сложности и навороченности. На всякий случай - не жалейте скобок, чтобы не лазить в справочник по приоритету операторов.

Comment: на мой взгляд, лучше комплексные условия выносить в отдельный метод , с осмысленным названием

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите что бы выполнялись сразу два условия для цикла можно написать так `while number1 > 0 and number2 > 0:`, что бы цикл работал по одному условию, можно сделать как вы и написали через `or`

Comment: Тогда в чём разница между while и if?